# OpenVPN connected but IP not changing

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

This question might be common for OpenVPN users, but I am very frustrated, since every solution failed.  I tried almost every solution that I could see on the Internet for this problem.  I set up an OpenVPN on CentOS 7 NAT vps server.  Then I installed OpenVPN GUI on my laptop (Windows 7).  At first it was OK: it connected and the IP address changed. 
But a few moments later, it again unmasked, back to real IP.  I tried these:

1. Compatibility - right click on OpenVPN GUI, run this program in compatibilty mode → tried almost all.
   IP address changed for almost one minute, again automatically changed to original.
2. Disable IPv6 - Go to Control panel → Network and internet → Network connections → Right click on tap Windows adapter v9 → then disable IPv6.
   Not working.
3. redirect-gateway def - Edit `config.ovpn` file on server and add `push "redirect-gateway def1"` and edit client `config.ovpn` file on Windows 7 and add `redirect-gateway def1`.  Still nothing worked.

I am clueless. Here is the log file from the client:

```
Thu Aug 24 23:55:03 2017 OpenVPN 2.4.3 i686-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] built on Jul 14 2017
Thu Aug 24 23:55:03 2017 Windows version 6.1 (Windows 7) 32bit
Thu Aug 24 23:55:03 2017 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017, LZO 2.10
Enter Management Password:
Thu Aug 24 23:55:03 2017 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Thu Aug 24 23:55:03 2017 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
Thu Aug 24 23:55:03 2017 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Thu Aug 24 23:55:04 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
Thu Aug 24 23:55:04 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
Thu Aug 24 23:55:04 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'echo all on'
Thu Aug 24 23:55:04 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
Thu Aug 24 23:55:04 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
Thu Aug 24 23:55:05 2017 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Thu Aug 24 23:55:05 2017 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Thu Aug 24 23:55:05 2017 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]104.152.190.126:17600
Thu Aug 24 23:55:05 2017 Socket Buffers: R=[8192->8192] S=[8192->8192]
Thu Aug 24 23:55:05 2017 UDP link local: (not bound)
Thu Aug 24 23:55:05 2017 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]104.152.190.126:17600
Thu Aug 24 23:55:05 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1503597305,WAIT,,,,,,
Thu Aug 24 23:55:05 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1503597305,AUTH,,,,,,
Thu Aug 24 23:55:05 2017 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]104.152.190.126:17600, sid=d06722a6 e92e9a3e
Thu Aug 24 23:55:05 2017 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=ChangeMe
Thu Aug 24 23:55:05 2017 VERIFY KU OK
Thu Aug 24 23:55:05 2017 Validating certificate extended key usage
Thu Aug 24 23:55:05 2017 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
Thu Aug 24 23:55:05 2017 VERIFY EKU OK
Thu Aug 24 23:55:05 2017 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=server
Thu Aug 24 23:55:06 2017 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
Thu Aug 24 23:55:06 2017 [server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]104.152.190.126:17600
Thu Aug 24 23:55:07 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1503597307,GET_CONFIG,,,,,,
Thu Aug 24 23:55:07 2017 SENT CONTROL [server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Thu Aug 24 23:55:07 2017 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4,route-gateway 10.8.0.1,topology subnet,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.2 255.255.255.0,peer-id 0,cipher AES-256-GCM'
Thu Aug 24 23:55:07 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Thu Aug 24 23:55:07 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Thu Aug 24 23:55:07 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Thu Aug 24 23:55:07 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
Thu Aug 24 23:55:07 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Thu Aug 24 23:55:07 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: peer-id set
Thu Aug 24 23:55:07 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: adjusting link_mtu to 1625
Thu Aug 24 23:55:07 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: data channel crypto options modified
Thu Aug 24 23:55:07 2017 Data Channel: using negotiated cipher 'AES-256-GCM'
Thu Aug 24 23:55:07 2017 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Thu Aug 24 23:55:07 2017 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Thu Aug 24 23:55:07 2017 interactive service msg_channel=0
Thu Aug 24 23:55:07 2017 ROUTE_GATEWAY 10.211.52.95/255.255.255.255 I=40 HWADDR=00:00:00:00:00:00
Thu Aug 24 23:55:07 2017 open_tun
Thu Aug 24 23:55:07 2017 TAP-WIN32 device [Local Area Connection 2] opened: \\.\Global\{7A6A15EB-2846-4F03-8F06-E5B7B16FE4B7}.tap
Thu Aug 24 23:55:07 2017 TAP-Windows Driver Version 9.21 
Thu Aug 24 23:55:07 2017 Set TAP-Windows TUN subnet mode network/local/netmask = 10.8.0.0/10.8.0.2/255.255.255.0 [SUCCEEDED]
Thu Aug 24 23:55:07 2017 Notified TAP-Windows driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 10.8.0.2/255.255.255.0 on interface {7A6A15EB-2846-4F03-8F06-E5B7B16FE4B7} [DHCP-serv: 10.8.0.254, lease-time: 31536000]
Thu Aug 24 23:55:07 2017 Successful ARP Flush on interface [14] {7A6A15EB-2846-4F03-8F06-E5B7B16FE4B7}
Thu Aug 24 23:55:07 2017 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Thu Aug 24 23:55:07 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1503597307,ASSIGN_IP,,10.8.0.2,,,,
Thu Aug 24 23:55:07 2017 Block_DNS: WFP engine opened
Thu Aug 24 23:55:08 2017 Block_DNS: Using existing sublayer
Thu Aug 24 23:55:08 2017 Block_DNS: Added permit filters for exe_path
Thu Aug 24 23:55:08 2017 Block_DNS: Added block filters for all interfaces
Thu Aug 24 23:55:08 2017 Block_DNS: Added permit filters for TAP interface
Thu Aug 24 23:55:13 2017 TEST ROUTES: 1/1 succeeded len=0 ret=1 a=0 u/d=up
Thu Aug 24 23:55:13 2017 C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD 104.152.190.126 MASK 255.255.255.255 10.211.52.95
Thu Aug 24 23:55:13 2017 ROUTE: CreateIpForwardEntry succeeded with dwForwardMetric1=20 and dwForwardType=4
Thu Aug 24 23:55:13 2017 Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
Thu Aug 24 23:55:13 2017 C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD 0.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 10.8.0.1
Thu Aug 24 23:55:13 2017 ROUTE: CreateIpForwardEntry succeeded with dwForwardMetric1=3 and dwForwardType=4
Thu Aug 24 23:55:13 2017 Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
Thu Aug 24 23:55:13 2017 C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD 128.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 10.8.0.1
Thu Aug 24 23:55:13 2017 ROUTE: CreateIpForwardEntry succeeded with dwForwardMetric1=3 and dwForwardType=4
Thu Aug 24 23:55:13 2017 Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
Thu Aug 24 23:55:13 2017 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Thu Aug 24 23:55:13 2017 Initialization Sequence Completed
Thu Aug 24 23:55:13 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1503597313,CONNECTED,SUCCESS,10.8.0.2,104.152.190.126,17600,,
```

Here is config file code:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
remote 104.152.190.126 17600
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
setenv opt block-outside-dns
key-direction 1
verb 3
redirect-gateway def1
<ca>
```

Here is Server Config file :

```
port 17600
proto udp
dev tun
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
tls-auth ta.key 0
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
```

Comment: Step the first; how are you concluding the IP address hasn’t changed?

Comment: After Connect the vpn,i check it on whatismyipaddress.com and its showing my original ip. And i know my vps ip is from america and my original is Bangladesh.

Comment: Could you perhaps post the server config file as well, and maybe have a look a look at the Openvpn log on the server.

Comment: Maybe you want to check with `route print` in Windows *before and after* it "goes back to real ip".

Comment: The thing is, did it really "go back"? Or has it ever changed?

Comment: It is "go back" because sometimes i got it changed so i see america instead bangladesh in whatismyipaddress.com. then again its back to bangladesh :(

Comment: @Anonymous server config file :
`client
dev tun
proto udp
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
remote 104.152.190.126 17600
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
setenv opt block-outside-dns
key-direction 1
verb 3
push "redirect-gateway def1"`

Comment: This is the **client** config file, that you already posted. Kindly edit your original post to add the **server** config file. Some settings must match on both ends, that's why I would like to see both files. Also, you may have a log on the server, that could tell why the VPN is failing.

Comment: @Anonymous i just added server config file and edited the Question. see it

Comment: In your server config file there is `keepalive 10 120` directive, that means ping the client every 10 seconds and drop the connection if no reply is received within 120 seconds.

Just a hunch, but I am wondering if you have a firewall on your client, that is dropping the pings, and causing Openvpn to shut down. Have you looked at the logs files on the server (probably in `/var/log/syslog` or something).

Comment: All i find is  openvpn-status.log file in `/etc/openvpn` dir. there is no `/var/log/syslog` dir and no openvpn log file in `/var/log` dir.
here is log file:
`OpenVPN CLIENT LIST
Updated,Fri Aug 25 18:58:25 2017
Common Name,Real Address,Bytes Received,Bytes Sent,Connected Since
ROUTING TABLE
Virtual Address,Common Name,Real Address,Last Ref
GLOBAL STATS
Max bcast/mcast queue length,0
END`

Comment: Yes. that is Keepalive 10 second matter. i just edited it to 1000000000,then try to connect and its working. thanks.

Comment: @Anonymous Now its more confusing.after connected,i find ipv4 changed at http://whatismyipaddress.com but on other website like google or whatismyip.com its still the same ip. means no change.

Comment: Maybe the page has not refreshed because of your browser cache.
Also, you might want to add a directive like this in your config file: `log-append /var/log/openvpn.log` so as to have a log for Openvpn activity.

Comment: i am quiting using openvpn. i will use softether vpn soon.